# Click text words to read adjacent html5 audio file

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

I am using a code to highlight text words that are read with html5 audio, and it currently highlights the sentence being read.  Now I need it to do the following too (another option): When I click the sentence, it jumps to the adjacent part of the audio and gets it played.

The code being used is:

```js
var textHighlightOn = true,
    btnToggle = document.getElementById('toggleTxt'),
    textDiv   =  document.querySelector('.text-highlight')
    spns = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN"),
    audi = document.getElementById("adi");

audi.addEventListener("timeupdate", f1);

function f1(){
  var i;  
  for (i = 0 ; i< spns.length ; i++){
    var time = Number(spns[i].id.slice(2));
    if(time < audi.currentTime){
      
       if (i>0) {
       
           spns[i -1].classList.remove('active');
           spns[i -1].classList.add('active-prev');
       
       }
       
       spns[i].classList.add('active');
      
    }
  }
}

btnToggle.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(textHighlightOn){
       textDiv.classList.add('off');
    } else {
       textDiv.classList.remove('off');
    }

    this.innerHTML = 'Highlight ' + (textHighlightOn ? 'off ' : ' on');         

    textHighlightOn = !textHighlightOn;

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #008000;
}
.text-highlight span.active-prev {
   background: #fff;
}
.text-highlight span.active {
   background: #03a9f4;
}
.text-highlight.off span {
   background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<audio id="adi" controls>
  <source src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3"/>
</audio>

<button id="toggleTxt">Highlight on</button>

<div class="text-highlight">
  <pre>
<span id="ts0.5">Ok, we're trying this for a second time</span> ,
<br><span id="ts3">to test the ability</span>
<br><span id="ts6">to upload an M P</span>
<br><span id="ts9">3 file.</span>
<br><span id="ts10">Hopefully this will work!</span>

    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: what you're doing is checking the time and highlight accordingly. When a span clicked, just seek the pointer in audio to it's corresponding value(pass a data-value to spans which contains it's time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend loading jQuery to make your code more readable.

```js
var textHighlightOn = true,
    btnToggle = document.getElementById('toggleTxt'),
    textDiv   =  document.querySelector('.text-highlight')
    spns = document.querySelectorAll('span'),
    audi = document.getElementById("adi");

audi.addEventListener("timeupdate", f1);

function f1(){
  
  // remove all previous actives;
  [].forEach.call(spns, function(e){
      e.classList.remove('active');
      e.classList.remove('active-prev');
  });

  var i;  
  for (i = 0 ; i< spns.length ; i++){
     
    
  
    var time = Number(spns[i].id.slice(2));
    if(time < audi.currentTime){
      
       if (i>0) {
       
           spns[i-1].classList.remove('active');
           spns[i-1].classList.add('active-prev');
       
       }
       
       spns[i].classList.add('active');
      
    }
    
  }
}


// listen for clicks on the spans.
[].forEach.call(spns, function(spn) {

    spn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    
        for(var i in spns){
            
            

        }
        
        var time = Number(this.id.slice(2));
        audi.currentTime = time;
        
    });
    
});

// Toggle text highlight
btnToggle.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(textHighlightOn){
       textDiv.classList.add('off');
    } else {
       textDiv.classList.remove('off');
    }

    this.innerHTML = 'Highlight ' + (textHighlightOn ? 'off ' : ' on');         

    textHighlightOn = !textHighlightOn;

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #008000;
}
.text-highlight span.active-prev {
   background: #fff;
}
.text-highlight span.active {
   background: #03a9f4;
}
.text-highlight.off span {
   background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<audio id="adi" controls>
  <source src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3"/>
</audio>

<button id="toggleTxt">Highlight on</button>

<div class="text-highlight">
  <pre>
<span id="ts0.5">Ok, we're trying this for a second time</span> ,
<br><span id="ts3">to test the ability</span>
<br><span id="ts6">to upload an M P</span>
<br><span id="ts9">3 file.</span>
<br><span id="ts10">Hopefully this will work!</span>

    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks as usual :)  However when it reads until the 4th sentence for example, and I go back and click on the second, it should remove the white highlights from the sentences after the second, and re-highlights them as they get read again.  And it also keeps a blue highlight at the last sentence it reached.

Comment: @Mike, review it now :D

Comment: Perfect, thanks..  Ready for the third question the series?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603956/scroll-text-up-and-hide-it-as-it-gets-read-using-html5-audio