# Scroll text up and hide it as it gets read using html5 audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, audio

I am using a code to highlight text words that are read with html5 audio, and also reads the audio when clicking on the adjacent sentence.

What I need is to make the line being read disappears from the page, and the next line being read jumps in its place, and so on..  so by the end there is nothing left in the page but: 1- audio player, 2- "Highlight on/off" button, 3- "Scroll on/off" button.

So there are two options in the page, weather the user wants to see all the text together while being read, or just sees the line that is being heard (and the lines under it).

The code being used is:

```js
var textHighlightOn = true,
    btnToggle = document.getElementById('toggleTxt'),
    textDiv   =  document.querySelector('.text-highlight')
    spns = document.querySelectorAll('span'),
    audi = document.getElementById("adi");

audi.addEventListener("timeupdate", f1);

function f1(){
  
  // remove all previous actives;
  [].forEach.call(spns, function(e){
      e.classList.remove('active');
      e.classList.remove('active-prev');
  });

  var i;  
  for (i = 0 ; i< spns.length ; i++){
     
    
  
    var time = Number(spns[i].id.slice(2));
    if(time < audi.currentTime){
      
       if (i>0) {
       
           spns[i-1].classList.remove('active');
           spns[i-1].classList.add('active-prev');
       
       }
       
       spns[i].classList.add('active');
      
    }
    
  }
}


// listen for clicks on the spans.
[].forEach.call(spns, function(spn) {

    spn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    
        for(var i in spns){
            
            

        }
        
        var time = Number(this.id.slice(2));
        audi.currentTime = time;
        
    });
    
});

// Toggle text highlight
btnToggle.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(textHighlightOn){
       textDiv.classList.add('off');
    } else {
       textDiv.classList.remove('off');
    }

    this.innerHTML = 'Highlight ' + (textHighlightOn ? 'off ' : ' on');         

    textHighlightOn = !textHighlightOn;

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #008000;
}
.text-highlight span.active-prev {
   background: #fff;
}
.text-highlight span.active {
   background: #03a9f4;
}
.text-highlight.off span {
   background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<audio id="adi" controls>
  <source src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3"/>
</audio>

<button id="toggleTxt">Highlight on</button>

<div class="text-highlight">
  <pre>
<span id="ts0.5">Ok, we're trying this for a second time</span> ,
<br><span id="ts3">to test the ability</span>
<br><span id="ts6">to upload an M P</span>
<br><span id="ts9">3 file.</span>
<br><span id="ts10">Hopefully this will work!</span>

    </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```js
var 
// Controlls
textHighlightOn  = true,
showAllTxt       = true,
btnToggle        = document.getElementById('toggleTxt'),
btnToggleShowTxt = document.getElementById('toggleShowTxt'),
    
textDiv =  document.querySelector('.text-highlight'),
spns = document.querySelectorAll('span'),
audi = document.getElementById("adi");

audi.addEventListener("timeupdate", f1);

function f1(){
  
  // remove all previous actives;
  [].forEach.call(spns, function(e){
      e.classList.remove('active');
      e.classList.remove('active-prev');
  });

  var i;  
  for (i = 0 ; i< spns.length ; i++){
     
    var time = Number(spns[i].id.slice(2));
    if(time < audi.currentTime){
      
       if (i>0) {
       
           spns[i-1].classList.remove('active');
           spns[i-1].classList.add('active-prev');
       
       }
       
       spns[i].classList.add('active');
      
    }
    
  }
}


// listen for clicks on the spans.
[].forEach.call(spns, function(spn) {

    spn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    
        for(var i in spns){
            
            

        }
        
        var time = Number(this.id.slice(2));
        audi.currentTime = time;
        
    });
    
});

// Toggle text highlight
btnToggle.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(textHighlightOn){
       textDiv.classList.add('off');
    } else {
       textDiv.classList.remove('off');
    }

    this.innerHTML = 'Highlight ' + (textHighlightOn ? 'off ' : ' on');         

    textHighlightOn = !textHighlightOn;

});


// 
btnToggleShowTxt.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(showAllTxt){
       textDiv.classList.remove('show-all');
    } else {
       textDiv.classList.add('show-all');
    }

    this.innerHTML = 'See All Text ' + (showAllTxt ? 'off ' : ' on');         

    showAllTxt = !showAllTxt;

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #008000;
}
span {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}

.text-highlight span {
   display:block;
   margin-bottom:1px;
}

.text-highlight span.active-prev {
   display:none;
   background:#fff;
}
.text-highlight span.active {
   background: #03a9f4;
   display:block;
}
.text-highlight.show-all span {
   display:block !important;  
}


/* turn off highlight */
.text-highlight.off span {
   background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<audio id="adi" controls>
  <source src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3"/>
</audio>

<button id="toggleTxt">Highlight on</button>
<button id="toggleShowTxt">See All Text on</button>

<div class="text-highlight show-all">
   <span id="ts0.5">Ok, we're trying this for a second time,</span>
   <span id="ts3">to test the ability</span>
   <span id="ts6">to upload an M P</span>
   <span id="ts9">3 file.</span>
   <span id="ts10">Hopefully this will work!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi again! Thanks for the answer.. However what I wanted from the new button is to show all the lines by default, and when a line is finished being read it disappears (it starts normally with 5 lines, then the first line disappears after being read, then there are 4 lines, and so on). And without the new #ffc107 highlighting.. In fact in this case we can remove also the white highlighting, as the read lines disappear, so it is only now the blue highlighting for the first line..

Comment: @Mike, sorry if it took me a lot of time to reply (I try to make the best of my weekends). Review the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man, I wish you happy weekend, and happy coding! I know how programmers enjoy a challenge :)  It's working good now, but it removed the option of highlighted white read text that was before..  It should always be there when user is not click on "see all text" button, and when clicking it, it will disappear automatically as the previously read lines are gone.

Comment: @Mike, review now?

Comment: Super.. Thanks..  I'd hate to disturb you, but I have a different question that is not yet answered, and you see like the man who can have a say about it.  It would be great if you can check it out, just in your free time..  and thanks in advance..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617791/script-to-automatically-link-special-words-in-php-to-an-existing-page